# HP Wifi & Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-16.04

I just installed ubuntu 16.04 in my new HP laptop and completed the installation without any problems.

But the wifi and bluetooth is not working and not showing any wifi points around me.

I checked **ifconfig**

[image]

I checked **iwconfig**

[image]

Please anyone support me to how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The wireless device may be disabled. You can check with

```
rfkill list
```

For each wireless device it will tell you whether the device is soft-blocked or hard-blocked. If it is soft-blocked it can be unblocked from software (e.g. again using rfkill). If it is hard-blocked then you will need to refer to your laptop's manual how to unblock it; one of my HP laptops has a dedicated hardware switch, the other has this function mapped to Fn-F12 on the keyboard.